# how to get callback for telerik grid submitChanges method

Tags: javascript, ajax, telerik, submitchanges

I am calling telerik Grid's **grid.submitchanges()(FUNCTION1)** in javascript which is an async call and there is one **ajax synchronous callback (FUNCTION2**) after FUNCTION1.

The problem is sometimes FUNCTION2 is getting executed before the completion of FUNCTION1 as FUNCTION1 is Async call.

But I need FUNCTION2 to execute only after completion of FUNCTION1.

So Is there any way to get callback for telerik grid submitChanges(FUNCTION1)?
or
Can I make telerik grid submitChanges(FUNCTION1) a sync call?

Code-:

**//FUNCTION 1**

```
if (grid != undefined && grid.hasChanges()) {

    grid.submitChanges();
}
```

**//FUNCTION 2**

```
$.ajax({
        url: urlForTheController,

       type: 'GET',
      async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: { TotalConAssociation: noOfRows },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#AssociationWithDocument').data('tWindow').close();
            showConcepts(currentConceptIndex);
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact workings of the API you are working with (a link would be welcome)...

You can just add the call to function2 inside the code of function1.

Another solution is to make a serial composition of both functions and pass it as the callback of submitchanges. There are libraries that help you to not nest too much, like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) or [promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).